# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания? (3)

Tags: пунктуация

Мы говорили: о книгах, о культуре, о разных странах, о живописи, — а не о детских садах и школах.

или....

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, все знаки препинания, кроме запятых, лишние.

**Мы говорили о книгах, о культуре, о разных странах, о живописи, а не о детских садах и школах.**

Допустимо авторское тире между однородными членами (оно ставится вместо запятой), подчеркивающее противопоставление (если Вы находите, что сады и школы можно противопоставить книгам и культуре):

**Мы говорили о книгах, о культуре, о разных странах, о живописи — а не о детских садах и школах.**

Пример из Нацкорпуса:

> Тормоза в ней барахлили, тормоза ― а не зажигание! [Вера Белоусова. Второй выстрел (2000)]

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!